# Unable to load key from the properties file in Spring Boot, null with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am looking to load all the properties file into List, but it look like things are not working. I am following: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/. I am using Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value="classpath:endpoints.properties")
public class AppConfig {
    @Value("#{'${endpoints}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> endpoints;

    public List<String> getEndPoints() {
        return endpoints;
    }
    //To resolve ${} in @Value
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

When I used this below, I get exception. `Environment env` is null.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
    if(endpoint instanceof MethodEndpoint) {
        MethodEndpoint methodEndpoint = (MethodEndpoint)endpoint;
        List<String> endpoints = Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("endpoints", String[].class));
        return endpoints.contains(methodEndpoint.getMethod().getName());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edit:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class DecisionInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {
    @Value("#{'${endpoints}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> endpoints;

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        if(endpoint instanceof MethodEndpoint) {
            MethodEndpoint methodEndpoint = (MethodEndpoint)endpoint;
//          List<String> endpoints = Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("edr.soap.endpoints", String[].class));
            return endpoints.contains(methodEndpoint.getMethod().getName());
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        log.debug("DecisionInterceptor - afterCompletion executed ...");
    }

}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: @Environment is null

Comment: What kind of Bean is the class where you use Environment env?

Comment: import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - Please see the edit

Comment: In `DecisionInterceptor ` where is `private Environment env;` ?

Comment: So you say @Autowired private Environment env; is null, right?

Comment: Yes, Thats right...

Comment: @PAA Did you see this question, it looks like the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54212507/11733759

Comment: @lczapski - You're right, I used constructor injection to pass the value to DecisionInterceptor, now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the responses from the comments. 
It looks that it is similar problem to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54212507/autowired-not-working-in-endpointinterceptor). And it should be checked how `DecisionInterceptor` is constructed in `Configuration`.